# VScode on Mac - launch safari debug

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been looking for a launch.json config to launch safari with a url from my mac for debugging.  I can't seem to locate a way to launch the safari browser and open a url link.

I looked for some extensions, saw the older IOS debugger one and saw some preview in browser extension options.  I'm not sure if its possible.  I haven't stumbled across a something on the web yet.  I'm working with SFCC and a specific safari browser issue.

In the meantime I will try prophet debugger and setting up a default browser of safari on the mac.

Thanks